# Getting values from nested JSON using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, each

I am looping through a nested JSON object and I get stuck at accessing the sub items.

Here is a sample of the JSON file I am using. It passes the JSONLint test so it can be assumed it is OK.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "fleetcheckitemid": "1",
    "checkitemdesc": "Engine oil level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}, {
    "fleetcheckitemid": "2",
    "checkitemdesc": "Water level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}, {
    "fleetcheckitemid": "3",
    "checkitemdesc": "Brake fluid level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}]
```

I can access the "*fleetcheckitemid*"and "*checkitemdesc*" but I am unable to access the "*answers*": [{"fleetcheckitemid": "2","checkitemdesc": "Ok"},......values

In my controller I have the following code, but as soon as I hit the inner .each() loop I get an error: "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*"

**app.js**

```
$http.get("http://mymadeupdomain/api/getfleetchecks.php?fleetid=" + $scope.newFleetIDValue).success(function(data) 
{
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log("$scope.data: " + $scope.data); // WORKING - [object Object], ... [object Object] 

    $scope.answersArray = [];
    console.log("$scope.answers: " + $scope.answers); // EMPTY ARRAY - NOT INITIALISED YET 

    // Unable to access sub-items (answers) here
    $.each($scope.data, function(index, element)
    {
       var itemDescription = element.checkitemdesc; 
       console.log("itemDescription: " + itemDescription); // WORKING - Engine Oil Level

       var fleetcheckitemid = element.fleetcheckitemid; 
       console.log("fleetcheckitemid: " + fleetcheckitemid); // WORKING - 1....34

        $.each(this.answers, function(index, element)
        {
            var answers = element.answers;

            var fleetcheckid = element.fleetcheckid;
            console.log("element.fleetcheckid: " + element.fleetcheckid); // NOT WORKING
            console.log("fleetcheckid: " + fleetcheckid); // NOT WORKING
        });
    });   
});
```

Where are I going wrong with this? Can it be the [] brackets around the answers in the JSON causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other solution for your question.

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.data = [{
    "fleetcheckitemid": "1",
    "checkitemdesc": "Engine oil level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}, {
    "fleetcheckitemid": "2",
    "checkitemdesc": "Water level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}, {
    "fleetcheckitemid": "3",
    "checkitemdesc": "Brake fluid level",
    "answers": [{
        "fleetcheckid": "1",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Ok"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "2",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Low"
    }, {
        "fleetcheckid": "3",
        "checkvaluedesc": "Top-Up Required"
    }]
}];
  
  angular.forEach($scope.data,function(value,key){
      console.log(value.fleetcheckitemid);
      console.log(value.checkitemdesc);
        angular.forEach(value.answers,function(v,k){
            console.log(v.fleetcheckid);
             console.log(v.checkvaluedesc);
          });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do make for loop over `$scope.answers` instead of `this.answers`. Then do change the `$.each` 2nd parameter name which is the same as outer `element` variable. So when control in coming inside a function the

```
$.each($scope.answers, function(index, ele) {//also change variable here
   var answers = element.answers;
   var fleetcheckid = element.fleetcheckid;
   console.log("element.fleetcheckid: " + element.fleetcheckid);
   console.log("fleetcheckid: " + fleetcheckid); // NOT WORKING
}
```

Still not sure, how you are filling up values in `$scope.answers`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.forEach($scope.data, function(data1){
       console.log("fleetcheckitemid: " + data1.fleetcheckitemid); // WORKING - 1....34

        angular.forEach(data1.answers, function(data2)
        {
            console.log("element.fleetcheckid: " + data2.fleetcheckid); // NOT WORKING
            console.log("DESC: " + data2.checkvaluedesc); // NOT WORKING
        });
    });
```